# Every few minutes sound is reset

Tags: debian, audio

I'm running Debian testing and I have a script that sets the volume of speakers on startup that looks like this:

```
amixer -c 0 set Surround  50% > /dev/null &
amixer -c 0 set Center   100% > /dev/null &
amixer -c 0 set Front     80% > /dev/null &
amixer -c 0 set LFE       50% > /dev/null &
amixer -c 0 set Side      80% > /dev/null &
```

The problem I'm having is that this configuration is reset to the default every few minutes so I have to continuously run the script to fix my configuration.

I think it happens most often when I'm watching something that is using flash or a browser. I can successfully watch a movie with VLC without this happening.

Anyone have any clue as to what the problem is?

Comment: You probably should report this as a bug to the Debian maintainers. What's to say it will be fixed by the time Jessie is released if you don't? Running `testing` or `sid` means you're taking part in the social contract of making Debian as stable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be connected with [pulseaudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio).

See http://blog.waan.name/pulseaudio-setting-volume-from-command-line/
for a script which allows you to change the volume.

Comment: I agree with pulseaudio as responsable. Look at message #27 on this thread
http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=556971
Look this lines:
Severity: normal

simply in default.pa commenting the lines

load-module module-device-restore
load-module module-stream-restore
load-module module-card-restore

solves the issue, too.

Comment: Or from message #47 installing alsa-utils will do it too.

Comment: You may be right that it is connected to pulseaudio, but the problem I am having is not the same as the one listed in any of the links. I'm having the problem of the sound settings resetting every few minutes. Not only at reboot. I tried all of the fixes listed and none of them worked.

Comment: @nulvinge can you post your  and asoundrc?
Can it be related to priority of the process as stated here?
https://wiki.debian.org/en/PulseAudio#Wheezing_and_audio_interruptions